# I am getting the following error while installing pystruct even though numpy is installed

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the pystruct package using pip, but I'm encountering an error related to the numpy module. I have already installed numpy on my system, but the installation of pystruct fails with the following error message:

```
C:\Users\GOD WORLD>pip install pystruct
Collecting pystruct
  Downloading pystruct-0.3.2.tar.gz (5.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.6/5.6 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\GOD WORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-y9y1efyl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\GOD WORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-y9y1efyl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\GOD WORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-y9y1efyl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\GOD WORLD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-y9y1efyl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

I have verified that numpy is installed on my system by running pip show numpy, which shows the installed version without any errors. I have also tried upgrading pip to the latest version using pip install --upgrade pip.

Is there any additional troubleshooting step I can take to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `pip show numpy` or `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: yes but did not work

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy` to make sure that it is installed to the current python.